# "Look! The sun rises" vs. "Look! The sun is rising"

Tags: present-tense, progressive-aspect, present-progressive

I know that theoretically you can use both statements in English:
a) Look! The sun rises.
b) Look! The sun is rising.

But is anybody (who is a native speaker) saying "Look! The sun rises."?

In German, for instance, it is absolutely normal (and common) to use the equivalent of statement "a".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wake up early and see the event of 'the rising of the sun', you would almost always say

> Look! The sun is rising.

Or other expressions such as one of the following:

> Look at the sunrise! 
>   Look, the sun is coming up!

This is because the present participle is the tense most often used to refer to what someone or something *is doing* at the moment of speaking.

As for the present simple

> Look, the sun comes up!

and

> Look! The sun rises.

These are not normally going to be used in the context of waking up and telling someone to look at the rising of the sun. For that, you're almost always going to use the present participle.

The simple present alternatives *can* be used for that, but such a usage would be uncommon. So, it wouldn't be wrong to say it, but it would seem strange. A native English speaker would be deliberately departing from normal usage.

> The sun rises

and

> The sun comes up

are usually reserved to express habitual events

> The sun rises/comes up each day

or to give the time of a single event

> The sun rises/comes up tomorrow at 0635.

You could preface this with *look* to draw attention to this fact, as in

> Look! The sun rises/comes up tomorrow at 0635, so we better get up at 0600 so we have plenty of time to see it.

There are additional uses of the present simple, which you can find by searching this site.

Comment: Sorry to be fussy, but the (perfectly common) usage of ‘present’ for participles ending in ‘-ing’ is rather misleading.  For example, ‘going’ can be used in a present (‘I am walking along the Thames’), or a future (‘I am leaving for New York next Tuesday’) or past (‘Five year’s ago I was working for Google’).  It’s a funny old language is English.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, hardly any native speaker would choose to say 'The sun rises'.

Longer answer: English has three verb forms that show the present tense: simple, progressive, emphatic. The forms that express these have other nuances to them beyond the present, and there are other forms that involve present tense, but these three are generally considered to have the present tense as the most central part of their semantics.

- simple: 'The sun rises'. This sounds like a plain static fact. It can work for an event right now ('look at the sun over there!', or it can refer to a universal occurence with no time at all ('Morning is the time around when the sun rises').
- progressive: 'The sun is rising'. This sounds like a process happening right now. Its aspect is continuous in that it hasn't stopped yet.
- emphatic: 'The sun does rise'. This sounds most natural as a response to a prior negative statement. "The sun doesn't rise on cloudy days" "No, the sun *does* rise, it is just behind the clouds".

As far as popularity or naturalness, standard English almost always employs the progressive. The present simple is perfectly grammatical and recognizable by native speakers, but sounds stilted and unnatural in most contexts.

It is an unfortunate habit in language learning of English (or for English speakers learning other languages) to give so many elementary examples using the present simple because it's just not used in everyday speech (telegraphic situations, like headlines or poetry, may use it more frequently; also the periphrastic use of the helping verb lends an informal tone.